# Why is BitConverter slower than doing the bitwise operations directly?

Tags: c#, bit-shift, bitconverter

I recently did some profiling on some code and found that the largest CPU usage was being consumed by calls to BitConverter such as:

```
return BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { byte1, byte2 });
```

when switching to something like:

```
return (short)(byte1 << 8 | byte2);
```

I noticed a huge improvement in performance.

My question is why is using BitConverter so much slower? I would have assumed that BitConverter was essentially doing the same kind of bit shifting internally.

Comment: What is the "huge improvement"? Not having the overhead of a function call will always make a difference. Since this is a very short function, the function overhead will be relatively large. Does the difference go (mostly) away when you allow inline expansion (compiler optimization)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to `BitConverter` involves the allocation and initialisation of a new object. And then a method call. And inside the method call is parameter validation.

The bitwise operations can be compiled right down to a handful of CPU opcodes to do a shift followed by the or.

The latter will surely be faster because it removes all of the overhead of the former.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs.html#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs#64128518fca2c03f) and see that it has a few extra things to worry about, notably parameter validation and endianness worries:

```
public static unsafe short ToInt16(byte[] value, int startIndex) {
     if( value == null)  {
          ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.value);
     }

     if ((uint) startIndex >= value.Length) {
          ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.startIndex, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Index);
     }

     if (startIndex > value.Length -2) {
          ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource.Arg_ArrayPlusOffTooSmall);
     }
     Contract.EndContractBlock();

     fixed( byte * pbyte = &value[startIndex]) {
          if( startIndex % 2 == 0) { // data is aligned 
              return *((short *) pbyte);
          }
          else {
              if( IsLittleEndian) { 
                   return (short)((*pbyte) | (*(pbyte + 1) << 8)) ;
              }
              else {
                   return (short)((*pbyte << 8) | (*(pbyte + 1)));                        
              }
          }
     }
}
```