# Convert byte array to generic type value in C#

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I would like to have a helper method for converting byte array to generic type value:

```
public static T BytesToValue<T>(byte[] bytes)
{
    int pos = 0;
    T result = default;
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        //Cannot convert from type byte to T error here
        result |= ((T)b) << pos;
        pos += 8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that the compiler gives the error.

The method will primarily be used for getting int and long values and performance is very critical.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like `BitConverter.ToInt64(byte[], int)`?

Comment: This isn't going to work. You also can't apply arithmetic operators to values with generic types, so the `<<` won't work either.

Comment: May be the answer on this topic helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616621/how-to-deserialize-byte-into-generic-object-to-be-cast-at-method-call

Comment: dymanoid, yes. I'm trying to implement an alternative to BitConverter becuase the latter is slow compared to bitwise operations.

Comment: @yaugenka I'd be very surprised. On my hardware, your method takes 7 ns to execute and `BitConverter.ToInt64` takes 3 ns. `BitConverter.ToInt64` uses unsafe context (so no bound-check) and loop unrolling, there's no way your version is going to be faster

Comment: Kevin, I was relying on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355107/why-is-bitconverter-slower-than-doing-the-bitwise-operations-directly. There is one more thing, which I did not mention in the question, is that I'm converting 24 and 40-bit value into Int and Long types, which would require additional operations when using BitConverter to fill in the missing bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitwise operators can't be used on generic type parameters.

Even this simple cast does not compile:

```
result = (T)b;
```

But we can write this that compiles (usefull for other case):

```
result = (T)Convert.ChangeType(b, typeof(T));
```

So this does not compile:

```
result |= ( (T)Convert.ChangeType(b, typeof(T)) ) << pos;
```

Comment: If I use `((int)b) << pos` it works, so why would `((T)b) << pos` not work when T is of type int?

Comment: T (generic type parameter) can be any type. We can only operate on integer numbers because of the architecture of the processor that uses bytes as units. Applying bitwise operators on references is not allowed as it will change the memory address of an instance of a type unless overloading these operators to act on an embedded value. Hence bitwise operators can't be used on generic type parameters that can match any reference of an instance of a type. And C# uses immutable for programmers references, not pointers. `((int)b) << pos` compiles because it is a integer number value type.

Comment: Then the suggested `Convert.ChangeType` should not work either, should it? It gives "Operand << cannot be applied to operands of type T and int" error with it.

Comment: Indeed. Answer updated to be more clear about what I tried to say.

Comment: If I use ulong type for the bitwise operation itself and then cast the result to a desired type (which is either Int or Long in my case) as suggested, will performance suffer? Or should I better have two separate methods for Int and Long convertions? The reason I ask this is that performance is really critical. I have gigabytes of bynary 24 and 40-bit data which need to be converted to Int and Long respectively quite often.

Comment: You must pay attention to the sign bit with bitwise operations and with casting else you will get unintended results. I have not considered these operators for a long time so I forgot the detail. For performance you should have different methods, for ulong, for long, for int, for uint and so on. Generics means less performance but more abstraction, less code and more maintainability. With ChangeType you lost more cpu ticks than a simple cast.